# Super-intelligent fungus?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, xenobiology

How scientifically plausible is this? A giant, self-aware fungal supercomputer made or evolved from something like the Blue Mountain honey fungus or maybe a slime mold of a similar size? Could something like this ever exist in nature as an example of distributed intelligence, or would it have to be created?

It has to explicitly be self-aware and just as intelligent as humans. The ability to modify its own genes to secrete chemicals that'll attract new prey is a bonus, but frankly I'll settle for a plain ol' giant mushroom supercomputer xP

Comment: I wonder what sort of powers this mushroom will give Mario?!

Comment: We arrested this man earlier. He started spouting nonsense about saving a princess and jumping on monsters... It all made sense once we found the mushrooms.

Answer (score 8):

If you're delving into the intelligence of mushrooms, you might want to take a look at some of Paul Stamets' work on the subject.

Distributed intelligence is likely your best bet. Mycelium works in concert and symbiotically so, there's a two routes I would go were I looking to create such a thing.

- **Symbiosis leads to hyper intelligence**
  In this case, mushrooms or fungi attaches itself to another creature which has had an evolutionary push in the direction of tools, hands and language. The creature it is attached to may actually be less intelligent prior to the fungi becoming part of it. The fungi evolved in this way in order to spread more efficiently and create and environment more suited for itself. The host creature benefits by becoming smarter and being better able to survive, through such things as chemical secretion. The mushroom bit might be only part that serves for a higher functioning and brain-power, but this would solve the problem of mobility and the evolution of hands. There are animals upon which fungi grows. A sloth-like creature might be a good start. If the fungi rewires it enough, it may become faster and when it is totally taken over, looks less like a sloth and more like a mushroom.
- **Networking Intelligence** In this version of things, the more of them there are in an area, the smarter they are. Mycelium is highly adaptive. This intelligence has helped them to survive more efficiently.  While they might be as smart as humans or smarter, they would not necessarily communicate using sounds and words. Their entire language can be chemically based. Each bit of them performs a specific function of thinking in the colony, though they all share knowledge. In this case, one mushroom may actually be mobile, while the others just hang out in the soil.

Comment: Here's a link to a cool article on their adaptive qualities, and thus their benefits to a creature they have symbiosis with: http://discovermagazine.com/2013/julyaug/13-mushrooms-clean-up-oil-spills-nuclear-meltdowns-and-human-health

Comment: The first half is the plot of a zombie game... I don't remember what it is called.

Answer (score 3):

My concern would be the energy required to maintain sentience. The human brain is a calorie hog, taking 20% of the body's energy supply. Fungi, making a living by decomposing stuff, survive on much less energy than any mammal, and they don't have access to the 25 watts or so that the human brain needs. (This, by the way, is an incredible adaption. Compare this to the rating of your computer)

Distributed intelligence makes thinking slow. Chemical signals are passed relatively slowly (compared with electrical ones). A large brain is a slow brain, but this at least lowers the power requirements. The fungus might think like Pratchets A'tuin, with each idea taking days to form.

Of course these problems can be handwaved away. But a being that thinks and experiences 100 times slower than we do. [Among Earth animals](http://www.independent.co.uk/news/science/q-why-is-it-so-hard-to-swat-a-housefly-a-it-sees-you-coming-in-slow-motion-8818124.html), those with small, fast brains: like a housefly, can process visual information 7 times faster than we can. Where as large brains, in a low energy configuation, (the leatherback turtle) are three times slower.

Could this fungus evolve-- tricky. It would depend on the environment. Intelligence would normally evolve as the end of an arms-race, or perhaps from sexual selection. Humans evolved intelligence perhaps because they there was a need to be highly mobile and adaptable -- hard to fit this model to a fungus.

The fungus needs to be able to act in someway. I suggest animal symbiots. The fungus thinks up the strategy. The symbiotic animals carry it out. So to hunt the bisonolopes that live in the forest, the fungus thinks up "throw sharp stones at them", the symbiots do the sharpening and throwing. The carry the spoils back to the nest. (think of a [leaf-cutter ant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ant%E2%80%93fungus_mutualism) as a model)

Answer (score 1):

Sure why not?

All you need for intelligence is communication pathways and signal discrimination.

That's a computer science AI perspective though.  From a evolutionary biology point of view the question is, why does a fungus have hard intellectual problems to solve?  It wouldn't bother getting smart unless it needed to. If you want to satisfy the biologists the fungus needs to benefit from this calorie consuming intelligence in some way.